# Divs inside contentPlaceHolder or ContentPlaceHolder inside Divs?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html

this is how my asp.net mvc master page looks like

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="blueBar"></div>


    <div id="globalContainer">

        <div id="pageHead">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="pageHeadPlaceHolder" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

        <div id="content">            
            <div id="mainContainer">
                <div id="leftColContainer">
                      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="leftColPlaceHolder" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div id="contentCol">
                      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentColPlaceHolder" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="pageFooter">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="pageFooterPlaceHolder" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is 
Whether the Divs present here are correct or they should be in the Content Views
I mean should there be here just the contentPlaceholders here and everything else in the content pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave the divs in the master page you won't need to repeat their definition in each view that uses this page. So it seems better to leave them as you currently have and only override the actual contents in the child pages.